# Updating location iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, core-location

I'm trying to get the app to update the user's location as the user moves, and update POI based on his location. It doesn't work right now (the user's location stays the same even if he moves by a lot). Can anybody help me out?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000;
    [mapView removeAnnotations: mapView.annotations];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    homeCoordinate = newLocation.coordinate;
    if (!home1Annotation) {
        home1Annotation = [[MyMapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:homeCoordinate
                                                               title:@"Current Location"
                          ];
        [mapView addAnnotation:home1Annotation];
        [self adjustMapZoom];
        [self loadAndSortPOIs];
        for (int j =0 ; j <5 ; j++){
            [self displayPOIs];
        }
    }
}
```

My Map Annotation

```
#import "MyMapAnnotation.h"


@implementation MyMapAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate;
#pragma mark initializers

// designated initializer
-(id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinateQ title:(NSString*) titleQ {
    if ( self = [super init]) {
        coordinate = coordinateQ;
        title = titleQ;

        [title retain];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark MKAnnotation implementation

-(NSString*) title { return title; }

-(NSString*) subtitle { return nil; }



@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things go wrong:

1) ask for the highest accuracy: `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` instead of `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters`. Don't set `distanceFilter` or set it to zero.

2) in `didUpdateToLocation`, add a line

```
NSLog(@"Location update: %@",newLocation);
```

and watch logfile output. Your `if` statement makes that the code block below is only run once. I would expect an `else` block, which will update the POI location in case the `home1Annotation` already exists. Something like:

```
} else {
     [MyMapAnnotation setCoordinate:homeCoordinate];
}
```

(but I do not know your class `MyMapAnnotation` so this is guessing)

Comment: Thanks for your help... 1) is corrected, but I'm not sure I get 2) right...can you edit the code given in my question to help me understand better?

Comment: You would have to share `MyMapAnnotation` if you want any help on that.

Comment: I should add `NSLog(@"Location update: %@",newLocation);` after this code     
`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    homeCoordinate = newLocation.coordinate;     
`
And then after
`for (int j =0 ; j <5 ; j++){
            [self displayPOIs];
        }`
I should add 

`} else {
     [MyMapAnnotation setCoordinate:homeCoordinate];
}`

Right?

Comment: the app crashes after 3 seconds.XCode tells me that MapAnnotation will maybe not respond to setCoordinate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3278/discussion-between-danskcollignon-and-mvds)

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problems, all will work, but in your case next call about user location changed will be called when user will cane their place from recent detection on distance of 1 kilometer as you specified by this code `locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000;`